# Prove that $X\subset Y \Rightarrow \bar{X}\subset \bar{Y}$

Tags: general-topology

**EDT.** $\bar{X}$ is the *closure* of $X$.

**EDT**.  The exercise is picked from a chapter which discusses metric spaces, therefore I believe it is implied that $X$ and $Y$ are contained in $M$, metric space.

---

I am currently completely stuck on how to prove the statement as formulated in the thread title.

If anyone could give me a hint on how one could solve this problem it would be very appreciated.

Comment: How do you define closure?

Comment: So far, I have assumed that $\bar{X}=\bigcap_i A_i$ where $A$ is a closed set and also such that $X\subset Y \subset A \subset M$ (here I am referring $M$ as a metric space, accordingly to the edit I made to my post).

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{X} = \bigcap \{A | X \subset A, A \text{ closed}\} \subset \bigcap \{A | Y \subset A, A \text{ closed}\} = \overline{Y} \text{ since X contained in Y }$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\overline{X}$ is contained in every closed set containing $X$.  In particular, $\overline{Y}$ is a closed set containing $X$.  So $\overline{X}$ is contained in $\overline{Y}$.